# How to getBodyElement() in RootLayoutPanel GWT

Tags: dom, gwt

I want to make a progress bar before my application starts.
Here the code from my html page

```
<body>
    <div id="appLoading">
        <img src="images/bar.gif" />
    </div>
...
</body>
```

And later on the client side I wrote

```
DOM.removeChild(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), DOM.getElementById("appLoading"));
```

But now I'm using `RootLayoutPanel` and it doesn't have `getBodyElement()` method. So help me please explain how to remove my progress bar now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove it. When you attach a RootLayoutPanel (after your app is loaded and starts), it will take over the entire browser screen, and your progress bar (and any other HTML in your host page) won't be visible.

If, for some reason, you still need to get the BodyElement, you can do it by calling

```
Document.get().getBody();
```